# GCM and iOS bridging header does not exists

Tags: ios, swift2, google-cloud-messaging, bridging-header

I have been trying to get the GCM to work on my iOS app but it keeps giving me an error. I am trying to just add it into my project but keeps saying that there is no bridging Header file for it. I have a bridging header file just like the one from the example project and I linked it to the Swift Compiler like I was told to do. I don't know if I am doing this right. Here is how my build setting looks 
[image]

This is the line I used to add the header (Sub ProjectName for the real name of the project)
"$(SRCROOT)/$(ProjectName)/BridgingHeader.h"

and here is how my pod file look like

```
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
pod "SwiftyJSON", "= 2.3.2"
pod "Alamofire", "= 3.2.0"

end

target 'ProjectTests' do

end

target 'ProjectUITests' do

end
```

Thank you for any help with this I am stumped a bit on what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it fixed. I had to select the Objective-C BridgeHeader and press delete. Then once that has been cleared out. I double clicked onto it again and added this ProjectName/BridgingHeader.h.
Now it works.
Thank you for reading the post and I hope that this helps someone too.